# Group criteria updates through advanced search when no rights granted. Is this a bug?

Tags: groups, acl

Environment:

- Drupal 7.53
- CiviCRM 4.6.24 LTS

For MailUsers in Drupal Permissions, I have it set to:

- CiviCRM: edit groups (No Rights for MailUsers)(only Admin has this)
- CiviCRM: administer reserved groups (No Rights for MailUsers)(only Admin has this)

It does show correctly on the Manage Groups pages for a user with Authenticated and MailUser only rights, but if I click contacts for a group (reserved group or not) in this page, it then presents me with a page with contact results and a button "Edit Group Criteria (Smart Group or not)".  I can then edit the group criteria and then select all results and in the Actions dropdown on that page I can tell it to update the smart group, and then update the settings of the smart group.  I can also create a smart group through Advanced Search > Actions dropdown > New Smart Group.

This seems to be contrary to the rights set for MailUsers.

Is this a bug?